# If I'm a fairy cleric, can I cast Detect Evil and Good, and if I can, would I have disadvantage on the roll to see if it detects successfully?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I'm playing a fairy cleric. My thought process is that I am a fey, so if I cast [*detect evil and good*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-evil-and-good), it would detect me as well.

I was wondering if this would prevent me from using the spell, or if it would give me disadvantage on the roll to properly detect enemies because of the extra alarm going off in my head alerting me that I am nearby.

Comment: Related: [Do you count as "a creature within X feet" of yourself?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/157308/23547), [Does the Detect Magic spell detect itself?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/160826/23547)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Nothing in your racial traits or the spell description indicates your ability is impaired.

There’s nothing in your racial traits or the spell description that would indicate your ability to use the spell as written would be impaired by being a fey yourself. I don’t really have much else to say in the way of explaining why not. Your racial traits tell you how they work, and the spell description tells you what it does. There’s just nothing there to indicate that your race interferes with the spell’s function in any way.

Comment: Ok, just making sure before I prepare it

Answer (score 4):

### You're fine

There's nothing in the spell description that says how you know, you just know.  There's no alarm going off in your head, or the spell would say.  And there's nothing in the spell description that says that knowing interferes with anything else, so it doesn't.

Every time you cast it though, you'll know that there's a fey, **right where you are at!**  But don't worry, it's you.

That won't keep you from detecting all other aberrations, celestials, elementals, fey, fiends, or undead within 30 feet of you.

Comment: _Cf._ [Do you count as "a creature within X feet" of yourself?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/157308/23547)